# How to add a new language support to Bluefish editor?

Tags: ide, less

I'm working on LESS files under Bluefish editor.  Any idea about how to tell Bluefish that I want him to treat them (syntax coloring, auto indentation, etc) just like CSS files ?

I checked the preferences > language support, but it seems like you cannot add a new language support.  I think it might be handled in *~/.bluefish/rcfile-2.0*, but I'm not sure about how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add a language you just have to select CSS when you open a less file in the bluefish editor.
As i am using the German translation i am not sure about the right menu name look for something like:

Documents -> language mode -> select CSS in the now opened menu list

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

Bluefish has *.bflang2 files. They are instaled system wide, but they can also be loaded from .bluefish/less.bflang2

Check bflang2.bflang2 and sample.bflang2 for examples how to create a new language file.